# KiCad net names

Tags: pcb, layout, kicad

I'm trying to assign footprint's pad to a net in a schematic but for some reason nets in Eeschema aren't generated from components' pin names (EN, VIN etc.), but are always auto-generated (Net-(R1-Pad1) etc). This means, for example, that I can't assign pin 2 of U1 to net 'EN', since it doesn't exist.

[image]

What can I do about this?

Comment: Can you explain why you try to change the net of an instantiated footprint?

Comment: Because I want to map 6 logical pins on the schematic symbol to 8 real ones on the footprint. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes: create a schematic symbol that contains all the pins.

Answer (score 3):

You need to place a label on the net to name it. Otherwise KiCad will generate name for it. Power nets (those connected to 3V3, GND power symbols for example) are named automatically as 3V3 or GND.

Answer (score 0):

Net name should begin with `/` type `/EN` in the net name of the pad and it should work.

Comment: That didn't work.